# Maven Eclipse: Add maven jar project as a reference to an war project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I tried to add my custom jar maven project to an war project as dependency, but it still throws an `NoClassDefFoundError` if I try run it on Apache 7 server in Eclipse.

The pom of my .war Project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.dbbase.apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<!--    <parent> -->
<!--        <groupId>de.dbbase.core</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>jwtpom</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>0.0.1</version> -->
<!--    </parent> -->

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.1</ch.qos.logback.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Core abhängigkeiten für ein Web-Project  -->

        <dependency> <!-- For HttpSessionListener -->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To use @ManagedBean, @SessionScoped, ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
<!--            Wenn logback verwendet wird -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Sonstiges -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.dbbase.libs</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbbase-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and pom of my maven jar project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.dbbase.libs</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbbase-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.1</ch.qos.logback.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Core abhängigkeiten für ein Web-Project -->
        <dependency> <!-- For HttpSessionListener -->
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To use @ManagedBean, @SessionScoped, ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Wenn logback verwendet wird -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
        <!-- Sonstiges -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I export my war project as war, than the jar of my dbbase-auth Project will be in the libs folder. But every time I run the war project in Eclipse on Tomcat 7 server the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` will be occure for every class from my dbbase-auth jar project which I use in my war project.

**Edit:**

My Stacktrace looks like this:

```
@Pracede here is the stacktrace:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lde/dbbase/libs/auth/user/service/UserDBService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.dbbase.libs.auth.user.service.UserDBService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: That has never happened to me. Can you explicitly declare the dependency scope to <scope>compile</scope>?
Also, explicitly add the <packaging>jar</packaging> to your jar pom

Comment: Could you post the stackstrace error please ?

Comment: So it would seem that Maven handles the dbbase artifact correctly, but Eclipse does not? Perhaps your Eclipse project setup is to blame. I recall the Eclipse maven plugin being rather picky about workspace resolution of maven projects - but then I switched to IntelliJ :-)

Comment: @maress Explicitly adding packaging and scope will not change a thing cause the are default.

Comment: Check @Anders answer, that would be the problem

Comment: @maress do you mean i shoult change my **war** pom like this?: 

`<dependency>
    <groupId>de.dbbase.libs</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbbase-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

I have tried it befor, but this change nothing.

@AndersR.Bystrup for InteliJ IDEA first i need to save money :P

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup i have downloaded 30days trial of IntelliJ IDEA and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

AFAIK Tomcat does not provide an implementation of this API. Therefore your app will compile, but throw a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime.

Use a server that provides this implementation (i.e.[TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html))

Comment: **Case 1:** I have tested it with only one Project (without set up my dbbase-auth-Project as dependency) and i have no problems with javaee-api. **Case 2:** If i remove javaee-api dependencie from my war and my jar project, i have the same problem (nothing will be changed).

Comment: You'll only get this Exception when you try to use the API.

Comment: Thats not true, i have removed the api however the exception will be thrown again.